# Python Stopping a program at any point in an if command

Tags: python, if-statement

I currently have a program that I am working on that requires the user to input some parameters, and then press a button to start the main part of the program.

After the start button is pressed, the if loop executes a sequential order of commands (around 20) and then stops.

I want to be able to stop this sequence of commands at any time during the code using a separate 'stop' button, but I am not sure how. I am more interested in a method of doing this than GUI syntax.

Any help is appreciated.

Example code:

```
if (start_button_is_pressed):
    #do thing a 
    #do thing b 
    #do thing c 
    ...
    #do thing z

# i want to be able to stop from any point a-z
```

Comment: have you thought about testing if you need to stop in between a-b, b-c, c-d, etc?

Comment: @ACarter So the issue is that the user could determine to stop the if statement at any given time. For example, if they input the wrong parameters, they could realize this at any time and want to stop and restart at any point a-z.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop and break execution at any point.  If you want only a single pass through the steps, add a final break at the end.

```
jump_out = False
while not jump_out:
   step_1()
   if (jump_out): 
       break
   step_2()
   if (jump_out): 
       break
   # and so on
   step_n()
   break  # add unconditional break for single-pass execution
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a break statement inside the loop. Set an event such that when the stop button is pressed, it triggers a certain value and this value alters the loop. Sample process below

```
stop = False

if stop_button_is_pressed:
    stop = True

for a in b:
    if stop == True:
        break
    print(a)

print("Stopped")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `multiprocessing.Process` to `terminate()` the process/function `my_process_function()` whenever you please... Run it as script to get outputs.

```
import multiprocessing

def my_process_function():
    for i in range (100):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    print("my_process end")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_process_function())
    x.start()

    print("Stop thread?")
    a=input()
    if (a=="y"):
        x.terminate()
```